# MacOS development in ASP.NET Core 3.1 on Rider: Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I recently switched from a Windows machine with Visual Studio to a MacBook with Rider. I have a .NET Core 3.1 project that I upgraded from .NET Framework 4.7.2, and I am trying to configure Windows Authentication for it.

My MacBook is connected to a company domain via Enterprise Connect, and I have active kerboros tickets. AKA, I am able to access company resources that use Windows Authentication or otherwise pull my domain credentials. For example, I can login to the published version of my project which runs on IIS and .NET Framework 4.7.2.

However, I am not able to use Windows Authentication when I run the .NET Core 3.1 version locally. I have made the following changes to my project:

In `StartUp.cs`, added the following to `ConfigureServices`:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(nameof(Policy.AuthorizedUser), 
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new AuthorizedUserRequirement()));
});

services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, AuthorizedUserHandler>();
```

In `StartUp.cs`, added the following to `Configure`:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I did install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authenticate.Negotiate` package.

Created the Authorization handler and requirement:

```cs
public class AuthorizedUserHandler: AuthorizationHandler<AuthorizedUserRequirement>
{
    private readonly AuthorizationConfiguration _configuration;

    public AuthorizedUserHandler(AuthorizationConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AuthorizedUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        if (context.User.IsInRole(_configuration.User.Group))
        {
            // Call 'Succeed' to mark current requirement as passed
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class AuthorizedUserRequirement: IAuthorizationRequirement { }
```

Then, I apply it to my controller to restrict access:

```cs
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(Policy.AuthorizedUser))]
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
}
```

My configuration object is correctly injected. However, `context.User` is empty. When I debug my project and go to a page that uses this policy (in Google Chrome), I get the HTTP ERROR 401 default error page from Google Chrome.

How can I modify my code to fix this error, or otherwise setup Windows Authentication for local debugging on MacOS? I also tried using the Windows Authentication schema in `services.AddAuthentication` but that also failed.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that this is a supported scenario, and you're either going to use an alternative authentication scheme while developing on your Mac, or you're going to need to use a VM to run Windows.

Comment: I can't believe there is no way to do it (not that I disagree). I feel like my situation is pretty common and would be supported, especially since I am connected to a domain.

Comment: I haven't done .NET development on a Mac so I don't know for sure either. But Windows has plumbing in place to handle integrated Windows Authentication, and it's doubtful that Mac does, even if you can connect to a website that's actually protected by Windows auth. And I highly doubt your scenario is a common one: most people developing apps that use Windows auth will be on a Windows PC to avoid issues like this.

Comment: I know. I am only trying to set this up as it is a legacy application. Moving forward I won't be dealing with it. I was hoping there was a solution I missed that could prevent me from having to change authentication methods (or run a Windows VM).

Comment: According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel) this is a supported scenario and the required plumbing *is* Kerberos. Have you performed the [Linux and Mac OS configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#linux-and-macos-environment-configuration) steps? Have you created a keytab file for your machine?

Comment: I don't have access to our domain controller. That being said, I have active tickets when I run `klist`. I believe it as already done since I have a ticket beginning with `krbtgt`.